# Can't fix the Libpng issue in eclipse

Tags: google-play, libpng, android-security

when I submit my app, google play send me an email that my app is rejected because of the libpng library, I checked the [link](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7011127) they send me but I don't know what exactly should I do after instaling the new libpng on my mac, because the libpng files still exist in the app folder.

I tried to replace the Libs folder of my app with a libs folder contain updated libpng, google play accept the app but the app crash in startup!

Please tell me what should I do exactly to solve this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: No One can Help?

Answer (score 0):

You should adapt your app so it doesn't crash with the new version of libpng, then re-submit. Without giving details of the crash, and your code which calls libpng no-one can help you.